# How to find hashtag in HTML which ends with space or <?

Tags: regex, hashtag

I want to find hashtags in HTML by Regex.

```
<div class="details">
  <p>#hashtag1 #hashtag2 #hashtag3</p>
  <p>#hashtag4 #hashtag5 #hashtag6</p>
  ...
</div>
```

When I use this Regex:

```
var details = $('.details').html();
details = details.replace(/#(\S*)/g,'<a href="/?hashtag=$1">#$1</a>');
$('.details').html(details);
```

It returns:

```
<div class="details">
  <p>
    <a href="/?hashtag=hashtag1>#hashtag1</a>
    <a href="/?hashtag=hashtag2>#hashtag2</a>
    <a href="/?hashtag=hashtag3>#hashtag3</p></a>
  ...
</div>
```

How can I get this?

```
<div class="details">
  <p>
    <a href="/?hashtag=hashtag1>#hashtag1</a>
    <a href="/?hashtag=hashtag2>#hashtag2</a>
    <a href="/?hashtag=hashtag3>#hashtag3</a>
  </p>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: don't use regex to parse html. ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern `/#\w+/g`

```js
var input = '<p>#hashtag1 #hashtag2 #hashtag3</p>';

console.log(input.match(/#\w+/g));
```

`\w` means: A word character is a character from a-z, A-Z, 0-9, including the _ (underscore) character.

---

Update:

```js
var details = $('.details').html();
details = details.replace(/#(\w+)/g,'<a href="/?hashtag=$1">#$1</a>');
$('.details').html(details);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="details">
  <p>#hashtag1 #hashtag2 #hashtag3</p>
</div>
```

---

Update 2:

```js
var details = $('.details').html();
var pattern = /#([\p{L}\p{N}]+)/gu;

details = details.replace(pattern,'<a href="/?hashtag=$1">#$1</a>');

$('.details').html(details);

// for testing
console.log(details.match(pattern));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="details">
  <p>#nguyễn1 #nhựt2 #tân3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer solves the problem, but If the hashtag includes UTF-8 characters, it doesn't match.

Comment: @JeongyongLee Does my update 2 solve your problem?

Comment: Update2: Perfect! That's what I wanted exactly! Thank you! Cảm ơn!

Answer (score 0):

@Tân gave me the answer which I wanted exactly, but I found another way to solve this problem with jQuery.

If I replace the javascript(jQuery) part like this:

```
var $targets = $('.details p');
$('.details p').each(function () {
  var text = $(this).text();
  text = text.replace(/#(\S*)/g,'<a href="/?hashtag=$1">#$1</a>');
  $(this).html(text);
});
```

This solves the problem.